# Importance of giving an initial value to the variables "Local or global " javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering what is the importance of having an initial value for a variable in JavaScript.

```
function data() {
    var self = this;
    self.formatLength;
}

function data() {
    var self = this;
    self.formatLength =  null;
}
```

What if you do not give an initial value such as null or whatever value to that variable
then operate on it .

would it make a difference? Since I am new in JavaScript and trying to keep good habits and I was wondering about it.

Comment: If nothing else it helps prevent unexpected results since you're starting with an explicit value. You could ask this about any language. Why initialize a variable to a default value?

Comment: It is very bad practice to be using `self` as a variable. It is like using `alert` as a variable. Both of them are properties of the `window` object, and `self` is used to distinguish between the `top` window/frame object or the "local" window/frame object (different in the context of an `iframe`, for example).

Comment: @j08691 what i was wondering if there is anything particular with JS in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first constructor does not create the formatLength field. It just try to get a non-existing field.

The second constructor creates the formatLength field.

@lighty set a field to undefined doesn't make sense. In js a field can be null as in C#. undefined is 'value' you will get if are trying to refer a field which doesn't exist in the object.

```
var o = {};
var u = o.youField; // u is set to undefined;
```

undefined means the object doesn't define this field.

You can write that :

```
var o = { yourField :  undefined};
```

But I have never see this.
You should write this :

```
var o = { yourField :  null};
```

So, If you want un field with initial value (even null), you should write this :

```
var Class = function data() {
    var self = this;
    self.formatLength =  null;
}
var c = new Class();
```

And if you want remove this field you call delete as follow :

```
delete c.formatLength;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Give it an initial value if you want it to default to something. So that if you access it later on without setting a value, it will have something set.

If you don't set a value to it it will simply be `undefined`. This is a type in JS and can be checked for in your code.

Comment: Do you think there are some cases or you had an experience where you wanted to keep it undefined instead of null? All am trying to reach here is to understand TO DO and TO DONOT when it comes to JavaScript

Comment: When I don't know the values I want to assign, I usually leave it undefined at the top of my object so I have a reference of the properties of the JS object. I initialize them on the constructor. If I already know the values, I assign the defaults right away. Simply comes down to whether you know what you want to assign or not.